# Applying constructor attribute have no result

Tags: javascript

I'm explicitly define constructor property of just created object as the following:

```
var fooProto={foo:"prototype"};
function f(){ };
f.prototype=fooProto;
var object= new f();
object.constructor.prototype.bar="bar";
console.log(object.foo, Object.prototype.bar);
```

In the console we have `prototype,bar`, but i'm explicit `undefined,undifined`. Please explain why it's occuring?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What does *"but i'm explicit undefined,undifined."* mean?

Comment: I think you mean I'm `expecting`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding bar to the Object.prototype:

```
console.log(fooProto.constructor===Object);//true
console.log(object.constructor.prototype===fooProto);//true
```

After setting the prototype of `f()` you should repair the constructor:

```
f.prototype=...;
f.prototype.constructor=f;
```

If you were expecting undefined, undefined then I've just answered why the second one doesn't print undefined.

Why the first one isn't undefined is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941) in the introduction to constructor functions. Short answer; when you request members on an object and that object doesn't have that member/property then JS will look for it on the prototype of the constructor that created the object.

For example:

```
var test = {};
console.log(test.hasOwnProperty);//=hasOwnProperty(), not undefined
```

Test doesn't have a hasOwnProperty so where did it come from?

```
console.log(test.constructor);//=Object()
console.log(test.constructor.prototype.hasOwnProperty
  ===test.hasOwnProperty);//=true
```

So test got hasOwnProperty from Object.prototype and Object is the constructor of test